# Stacktrace in Spyder

Tags: python, windows-10, ide, spyder

I'm new to using Spyder.

While using breakpoints to debug, is there any way to check the stack-trace of the algorithm?
I want to check through which function calls did I land on the breakpoint.
[Similar to what we get when errors crop up].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's not possible at the moment, sorry.